# Differential equation drug administration

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A drug is administered intravenously at a constant rate of r mg/hour and is excreted at a rate proportional to the quantity present, with constant of proportionality k>0.

(a) Set up a differential equation for the quantity, Q, in milligrams, of the drug in the body at time t hours. Your answer will contain the unknown constants r and k.

My attempt:

I know that the differential equation to this word problem is $Q'=-kQ+r$, because there is clearly nothing else it can be.  But my question is why is this so?  I'm confused about the last part, +r.  It says that it is administered constantly per hour r mg/h.  But why do we put this r in our differential equation?  By adding this r into our differential equation, it's going to increase by $-kQ+r$ at very very tiny intervals, so the r will end up being added nearly infinitely many times in one hour, not once per hour, as the question says it should be.

Comment: $r$ is clearly given as **mg/hour**. So evaluating this over a minute or a second will not give you $r$, but the correct proportion of $r$.

Comment: Ah I see.  So in the above equation, if we take the instantaneous time differential equation, then we get the instantaneous version of r (lets call it $r_1$).  if I understood you correctly, you're saying that $r_1 \ne r$?

Comment: You are interested in **mg/hour** when you look at $Q'$,  and $r$ is in the same units; they are both differentials of **mg**. If anything it's the other term that is a little harder to explain. If there were no drug loss from the patient, $Q'=r$ would be perfectly valid.